# Text Template (.tt file), Define array and iterate through generating method for multiple types

Tags: c#

I am creating Numeric Extension methods and rather than write the same method multiple times, I want to use a Text Template file. However I can't find information on creating an array to iterate through to place the types needed for inputs, and outputs of the various methods. I have previously done so once, but it seems I can no longer find the information that helped last time, if someone could either point me to the right place or just help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Calculator
    {
    <# 
        var types = new string[] { "int", "long", "float", "double" };

        foreach(var T in types)
        {
    #>
        public <#=T#> Add(<#=T#> a, <#=T#> b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public <#=T#> Subtract(<#=T#> a, <#=T#> b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    <#
        }
    #>
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I don't know how I managed to forget that, Thank you.

Comment: This is great, is there a MSDN link that shows us how to compile this?

Comment: [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)